# Connection to test SFTP server on 0.0.0.0

Tags: python, connection, sftp, paramiko

I am trying to connect and upload / download a text file via Python, but I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Abdul\OneDrive\Desktop\SFTP neu\main3.py", line 8, in <module>
c.connect(hostname = "0.0.0.0",port = 22, username = "tester", pkey = k)
File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 349, in connect
retry_on_signal(lambda: sock.connect(addr))
File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\paramiko\util.py", line 283, in retry_on_signal
return function()
File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 349, in <lambda>
retry_on_signal(lambda: sock.connect(addr))
OSError: [WinError 10049] Die angeforderte Adresse ist in diesem Kontext ungültig
```

I'm using [Rebex TinySFTP Server](https://labs.rebex.net/tiny-sftp-server).

At first I thought my host was wrong, but that wasn't it.
In this example I used 0.0.0.0.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import paramiko

k = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file("C:\\Users\\Abdul\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\RebexServer\\private-rsa-key.pem")
c = paramiko.SSHClient()
c.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
print("connecting")
c.connect(hostname = "0.0.0.0",port = 22, username = "tester", pkey = k)
print("connected")
commands = ["C:\\Users\\Abdul\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\RebexServer\\data\\testfile.txt", "C:\\Users\\Abdul\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\SFTP neu\\data\\testfile1.txt"]
for command in commands:
    print("Executing {0}".format( command ))
    stdin , stdout, stderr = c.exec_command(command)
    print(stdout.read())
    print("Errors")
    print(stderr.read())
c.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> At first I thought my host was wrong, but that wasn't it. In this example I used 0.0.0.0

`0.0.0.0` is often used when *starting a server* to indicate that the server should bind to all available IP addresses. But it's *not* what you should use in your client.

Use one of the *actual* IP addresses your server is binding to. If both are on the same machine, try `127.0.0.1` or whatever IP address you are using locally. Addresses starting with `192.168.` are common in home and small office networks.